# iOS UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera fullscreen photo not capturing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, camera, uiimageview

I am implementing camera function in my app which will take photo. But i can not take fullscreen image. It shows me a rectangle to select the image area.

My source is like :

```
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

How to take a fullscreen image from camera ?

Comment: try after setting this - picker.allowsEditing = NO;

Comment: Yes, i tried before you told me. But thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change below line of code, this code allow the full size image

```
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable allowsEditing. This puts a rectangle to scale and crop the image.